# Only deploy classes JAR from a Maven WAR Project

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a Maven project which creates a WAR file as well as a JAR file (with the `-classes` classifier, using `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` in the `maven-war-plugin` config).  When I run `mvn deploy`, both of these artifacts gets deployed to Maven Central (via Sonatype Nexus).

That's all very well, but it's not really necessary to deploy the WAR to Maven Central - just deploying the `-classes` JAR would be sufficient, since the WAR is always uploaded to our github site for download, and only the JAR will ever be used as a dependency to another project.

Is there a way to configure this in Maven?  I thought that `<primaryArtifact>false</primaryArtifact>` in the `maven-war-plugin` config might fix it, but it did not.

Comment: Did you find a solution

Comment: @referee - No, sorry, it still uploads the WAR to Maven Central.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Maven WAR Plugin FAQs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached), this problem needs a bit of refactoring in order to be solved. You would have to split the project into one "classes" module that only produces the classes JAR, and a second module which builds the whole webapp into a WAR file. The WAR module can then include the JAR module as a dependency.

Different Maven profiles (one for building and deploying the JAR, another one to build the WAR and skip deployment) might be a solution too. But to be honest, that seems rather hacky and harder to maintain. I am not sure that it would make your life easier in the long run.